# jQuery ajax submitting a form and sending data to alternative domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, xss

I am currently looking into a couple of possibilities for a microsite that I am building. The microsite sits on a different domain to the main site, and we want to use some of the forms from the main site. However we don't the user to see the main sites thank you page for a form submission.

My question is, is it possible to submit the form on the microsite to the action of the main sites form, so essentially I am wanting to submit a form that is set on http://domain1.com to http://domain2.com.

Will I able to this due to cross-site scripting etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fighting with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy.
Possible solution will be using  a local proxy like http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html

Comment: Newer browsers allow you to relax the same origin policy.

Comment: @Erlend: Was not aware of that. Any link for more info?

Answer (score 0):

Using plain AJAX this is not possible, no.

You'd need to use a local proxy of some kind to achieve this. The form should submit it's data to a server side script on the same domain. That script should submit the data (using cURL or the like) to the remote location and give any response back to the form.

Comment: Sorry, but not true for newer browsers. See X-access--control-allow-origin

Comment: @Erlend true, but in typical Microsoft fashion you need a silly workaround for IE8/IE9 and it simply isn't possible in IE7 if thats a requirement which sadly it still is for a lot of people.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is possible, but with some restrictions. Newer browser support cross domain ajax using the x-access-control-allow-origin etc. headers. 
You could also use cross domain messaging (see CORS). To get backwards compatibility with older browsers, easyXDM is an option.

Another option is to build a hidden iframe, create a form, and send the data there using a normal for with action pointing to the other domain.

Remember though that Cross Site Request Forgery may be a problem. How do you stop other sites from posting to that same url.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to do this by placing the link to the action of mainsite in the microsite form. Also you can achive it via ajax, by sending call to the url of the mainsite and fetching results.

Comment: That wouldn't be possible via AJAX (which he specified) because you can't submit an AJAX request to a different domain.